# Git: which commands make a local repository identical to the remote one?

Tags: git, github

I have read git-scm.com/book and some questions on StackOverflow that have already been answered, but still have one question I don't get the answer for. Here is the use case:

Locally, I have cloned a remote repository (get clone). The repository is a rather big, thousands of nested folders and files. I work with files in this repository. Some of them are modified. Some others are deleted. Also, some files are added. After I'm done with those changes, I don't want to save them in my local repository (git add, git commit) and push/merge them to/with the remote ones (git push). All I want is the following:

a) files changed locally are being replaced by corresponding files from the remote repository (all conflicts are ignored, remote file versions have higher priority);

b) files missing locally are being copied from the remote repository;

c) newly created files that exist locally but don't exist remotely    remain untouched.

**Question**: with which set of Git commands am I able to get it done?

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
git reset --hard
git clean -df
```

The first command resets all tracked files, the second one removes untracked files. Note that this does not touch ignored files. Add `-x` to also remove ignored files.

Comment: Lukas, I may be wrong, but it doesn't work.  Files changed locally are NOT being replaced by corresponding files from the remote repository.

Comment: You are right, this is not exactly what happens. Instead, these commands should reset your local files to the state of your HEAD revision of your local repository. If you execute `git pull` after those two commands, your working copy should be updated with the latest changes from the remote repository. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Lucas, thanks! Very close to it. I didn't mention that in the initial question, but let me ask anyway: what if I delete a file locally, then do git commit *? After that, git reset --hard doesn't restore deleted file AND git pull doesn't copy it from the remote repository. In these circumstances, is it possible to recover this file? Why is this file not copied from the remote repository?

Comment: Once you have committed something, git pull will not move your branch pointer to anything before that commit. If you want to go back to an earlier commit, you can do `git reset --hard <commit>` where `<commit>` is the commit id you want to reset to. `git log` will show you the ids of earlier commits.

It sounds like you are not familiar with the concepts of git. Especially, git does not distinguish between local and remote repositories as you seem to think it does. I recommend reading an article about git's concepts like [this one](http://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/git/).

Comment: Lukas, thanks! Agree, I just started to work with Git and certainly have some holes in my understanding these concepts. I just tried specifying commit id and it got me what I wanted. Thanks you so much for your help!